# A question on primitive roots

Tags: nt.number-theory

Recall that for any prime $q$, the multiplicative group of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic, and hence a primitive root modulo $q$ exists for every prime $q$. For each prime $q$ choose a primitive root $g_q \pmod{q}$. Now let us fix a prime $p$, and for each prime $q \ne p$, define $x_p$ to be the integer in the range $[q+1, 2q-1]$ such that $g_q^{x_p} \equiv p \pmod{q}$. Since $g_q$ is a primitive root, this congruence has a solution.

Now, I am curious to know about the properties of the sequence $(x_p)_{p \text{ prime}}$. Is $(x_p)$ uniformly distributed? That is, for given positive integers $a,n$ do we expect roughly the same number of $x_p$'s, up to some bound $N$ say, to satisfy $x_p \equiv a \pmod{n}$? Is the behavior of $(x_p)$ more or less independent of the choice of primitive roots $g_q$ initially chosen?

Comment: I suppose the phrase "fix a prime $p$ and for each prime $q\ne p$" should actually read "fix a prime $q$ and for each prime $p\ne q$"? Also, can you say anything in the case $q=3$ (where $x_p$ can take just two vales, $4$ and $5$)?

Comment: Seva: Despite the notation, it seems that $q$ varying is more interesting.  If we fix $q$ and vary $p$, Dirichlet's theorem shows that each possible value of $x_p$ occurs equally often.

Comment: There's surely a dependence on the choice of the primitive roots (assuming my interpretation of the question is correct).  Look at the primes $q$ for which $x_p \equiv a\pmod{n}$, and then choose a different primitive root for each such $q$.  Why should the congruence $x_p\equiv a\pmod{n}$ be preserved for almost all of these $q$?  It might also be possible to hack together a sequence of $x_p's$ which are not equidistributed modulo any $n$, but I'm too tired to think through the details of this right now.

Comment: Yes for an individual $q$ surely the choice of primitive root matters, I am just trying to understand the "big picture" and whether, like you said, one can choose the primitive roots deliberately to bias towards a certain congruence class.